# How can I get the code coverage infos for assembly?

Tags: assembly, code-coverage

I want to do some researches on assembly level. However, it seems that there is not a tool for me to get infos for assembly, e.g. gcov, llvm-cov for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a debugger set a breakpoint on *every* source line, or on every instruction.  And have it remove the breakpoint after it's hit once.  Then run the program.

Then see how many breakpoints are still set.

That might be viable for small bits of hand-written asm as part of a larger program.  It would probably bog down if you want to do this for every compiler-generated asm instruction in a large executable + libraries, but is still viable in theory.

With something other than an interactive debugger to manage things, it might be viable in practice.